# file transfer in multi user chat to muliple users

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

i want to send files to multiple users in a one chat room so that i will be broadcasted to everyone. so far i havent found anything or any help on internet which resolve this issue.

currently what i tried is to send a single file to each users one by one but i think that is not an efficient way so if someone has another approach then please do let know.

i have tried sending file using `si-filetransfer` and `bystream` also. `socks5 bytestream` is not possible in javascript i guess so  i havent tried that.

i am using `openfire` server and `stophe.js` to send files using javascript and XMPP protocol

Answer (score 2):

Upload the file to a server (e.g. your OpenFire server) where users can download the file from.

To notify your users that they need to download a file, send them a stanza using XEP-0066: Out of Band Data or encode the link in a stanza as described in XEP-0071.

**References:**

- http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0066.html
- http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0071.html

Comment: when you say upload file at OpenFire server does it mean by `si-filetransfer` or `ibb` ?

Comment: None. I would say upload the file like you would using a HTML form in a web app (HTTP Post). Add some security though, you probably would not want non authorized users to upload files.